# Нужна помощь в написании метода parseInt на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется строковое (текстовое) представление числа.
Нужно реализовать функцию по конвертированию строкового представления числа, нельзя использовать библиотечные функции такие `parseInt` и д.р.

У нас имеется функция: `charToNumber(char: string) : number`

Функция принимает на вход один символ с цифрой и возвращает ее числовое значение.

Например:

```js
charToNumber(“2”) => 2 
charToNumber(“F”) => 15
// (F - цифра в шестнадцатеричной системе)
```

С ее использованием реализовать функцию по конвертированию строкового представления числа. Можно использовать любые операторы (циклы, арифметические операции), нельзя - библиотечные функции.

```js
function convertStringToNumber(stringNumber: string, base: number) : number
{

}
```

`stringNumber` - строковое представление числа

`base` - количество цифр системе счисления, в котором представлено `stringNumber`.

Примеры того что должно получится  на выходе:

```js
convertStringToNumber(“1111”, 2) -> 15
convertStringToNumber(“17”, 8) -> 15
convertStringToNumber(“123”, 10) -> 123
convertStringToNumber(“FF”, 16) -> 255
```

Comment: `ParseInt` выполняет другие функции. То что Вам надо называется конвертирование систем счислений. Также не видно Ваших попыток решить задачу, а только скопировано задание с Word'a. Также пример больше похож на typeScript, а не на чистый js

Comment: @Node_pro есть идеи как реализовать, parseInt(stringNumber, base) на javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Перевод в данном случае достаточно прост

1. нужно бежать по строке
2. значение на предыдущем шаге умножить на основание
3. прибавить значение текущего символа

Выглядеть это может так:

```
stringNumber.split('').reduce((acc, cur)=>acc*base + charToNumber(cur), 0);
```